# How to call firebase hook after some delay in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I am adding new users. On backend it takes about 2 second to give me access to new user data which I have created. The cause of the error is access control.When I try to get user using firebase hook it gives me an error :

> Error: permission_denied at /users/M2uQPQRacJZxjCwxqVT0UlHcwy72: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

After refreshing the page I am able to access the data of the new user and it is shown in list.

I would like to know is there any way to call firebase hook after some seconds so that I will not get this error?

Firebase hook:

```
 export const useUser = userId => {
   if (!userId) {
      return [null, false]
   }
   const ref = firebase.database().ref(`users/${userId}`)
   return useObjectVal(ref)
 }
```

usage:

```
import { useUser } from '../../hooks/firebase-hooks'

function TeamMemberListItem(props) {

  const userId = props.userId
  const [user, loading, error] = useUser(userId)

}
```

Comment: what is the cause of the error? Are you trying to show user before it is created?

Comment: The cause of the error is access control. On backend it takes some time to give me an access to new user data

Comment: is there some notification from the server when you get permissions?

Comment: no, but when I refresh the page it works. the backend developer told me to call the function after delay of 2 second then it will work

Comment: relaying on time delays isn't a good idea. Whati does `useObjectVal` do?

Comment: it returns [user, loading, error]

Comment: for starters ,you're breaking the rules of hooks: `useObjectVal` is called conditionally (only when `userId` is truthy)

Comment: it's not allowed to conditionally run hooks

Comment: if no userid exists then I am returning return [null, false]

Comment: instead of running `useObjectVal` conditionally, pass it `ref` conditionally

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I did understand, but did you try with a useEffect ? maybe if you use useEffect with userId as second parameter ?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

useEffect(() => {
 // do something when the component is mounted or userId is updated

 setInterval(() => {
   // do something 2 seconds after the component is mounted or userId is updated
 }, 2000);
}, [userId]);
```